# HostProtectionAttribute.Synchronization. Abstract class

Tags: .net, synchronization, thread-safety

I wonder about this attribute.  How derived class can be thread-safe when parent abstract class is decorated with this attribute.  What undelying mechanism is used here?  Does it mean that overriding abstract method will make that method thread-safe too?!